# Bootstrap Grid Aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a column in bootstrap grid system so that everything in the col is pushed to the right. I have tried the helper class pull-right but it doesnt do anything. I would like to be able to move elements in any of my columns to the left right or center on the fly but I think I am missing something.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Filter:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="Enter info">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

All I want to do is move the content in the right column to be right aligned https://i.stack.imgur.com/zphUl.jpg

I have tried creating a css rule called col-right with text-align right but that didnt do anything.

Comment: Have you tried using offsets? You can control how far to the right the column is. Pull-right just floats to the right. It might be helpful to get a graphic example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the layout. There is 3 cols and I want to push the form field in the right column all the way to the right.http://i.imgur.com/d9p8UdA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use the Bootstrap grid cols to achieve what your want, and then `text-right` to align the column content...

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-6 text-right control-label">Filter:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="Enter info">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/wKNm4JQqhV

Comment: Thanks for the comment I tried adding that class and nothing changed.

Comment: The text-right seems to work with a col with text in it but not these form fields. There must be some other properties overwriting this or keeping it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what your looking for?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Filter:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="Enter info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Filter 2:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field-2" placeholder="Enter info2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px7qgwc0/) working.